# Замедлить переход между сменой фото

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая мини галерея, подскажите пожалуйста как замедлить переход между фото, чтобы он не так резко переходил

```js
$(function() {


  $(".img-product").brazzersCarousel();

});


(function($) {
 $.fn.brazzersCarousel = function() {
  return this.addClass("brazzers-daddy").append("<div class='tmb-wrap'><div class='tmb-wrap-table'>").append("<div class='image-wrap'>").each(function() {
   var this_wrapper = $(this);
   this_wrapper.find("img").appendTo(this_wrapper.find(".image-wrap")).each(function() {
    this_wrapper.find(".tmb-wrap-table").append("<div>");
   });
  }).find(".tmb-wrap-table").bind('touchmove', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var myLocation = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
   var realTarget = document.elementFromPoint(myLocation.clientX, myLocation.clientY);
   var this_img = $(realTarget).parent(".tmb-wrap-table").closest(".brazzers-daddy").find("img");
   var all_thmbs = $(realTarget).parent(".tmb-wrap-table").find("div");
   this_img.hide().eq($(realTarget).index()).css("display", "block");
   all_thmbs.removeClass("active");
   $(realTarget).addClass("active");
  }).find("div").hover(function() {
   var this_img = $(this).parent(".tmb-wrap-table").closest(".brazzers-daddy").find("img");
   var all_thmbs = $(this).parent(".tmb-wrap-table").find("div");
   this_img.hide().eq($(this).index()).css("display", "block");
   all_thmbs.removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
  }).parent().find(":first").addClass("active");
 };
})(jQuery);
```

```css
/*!
 * jQuery Brazzers Carousel v1.0.0 (http://webdesign-master.ru)
 * Copyright 2015 WebDesign Master.
 */
 
 .img-product{
 width: 150px;}
 .img-product{
 padding: 50px;}
.brazzers-daddy:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
.brazzers-daddy {
 position: relative;
}
.brazzers-daddy img {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 display: none;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.brazzers-daddy img:first-child {
 display: block;
}
.tmb-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.tmb-wrap .tmb-wrap-table {
 display: table;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.tmb-wrap-table div {
 display: table-cell;
 transition: all .3s ease;
 border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
 padding-top: 10px;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 -o-transition: all .5s ease;
 transition: all .5s ease;
}
.tmb-wrap-table div.active {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #E94A26;
}
.tmb-wrap-table div:first-child:last-child {
 border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-product">
       <img src="https://185504.selcdn.ru/static/antkingdom.reshops.ru/catalog/12/4183998825b4914ed43910_small.jpg" alt="">
       <img src="https://185504.selcdn.ru/static/antkingdom.reshops.ru/catalog/13/16922066705b49004cd371e_small.jpg" alt="">
       <img src="https://185504.selcdn.ru/static/antkingdom.reshops.ru/catalog/12/4183998825b4914ed43910_small.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на луп внутри лупа. А вообще нужно или в jquery использовать дилэй или функцию/метод от яваскрипта setTimeout и setInterval ;ну если это луп внутри лупа то там как то за функцию выносить нужно , лень искать ответ, но если очень надо - напишите - я псмотрю что то